# Post Json Data to Rest API

Tags: rest, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing WP8 app and i'm new to it.. i want to know my post method is correct or not because i'm unable to post my data in the url it produces an exception..

My Class Contents...

```
public class Register     
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string password_reset_hash { get; set; }
        public string temp_password { get; set; }
        public bool remember_me { get; set; }
        public string activation_hash { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public bool activated { get; set; }
        public string permissions { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_login { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string conformpassword { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }      
    }
```

here is my code..

```
public  void btn_register_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url="myurl";
            Register res=new Register();// my class
            res.email = txt_email.Text;
            res.password = txt_password.Text;
            res.conformpassword = txt_conf_psswrd.Text;
            res.username = txt_username.Text;
            res.created_at = DateTime.Now;
            res.last_login = DateTime.Now;
            res.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
            res.status = true;

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var URI = new Uri(url);  
            wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";                
            wc.Headers["ACCEPT"] = "application/json";
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
            wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", json);             

        }

        private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Result); 
                //e.result fetches you the response against your POST request.         

            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); //i'm getting error here..
            }
        }
```

My Screen Design..
[image]

Error is..
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like there is a problem with the URI you are using. The error message you posted shows the server returning a "Not found" header. Maybe it just is not quite correct? I did not see the exact URI in the code you posted. `string url="myurl";` does not look like this is the url you want to use.

That's also why you can't access the response stream without an exception with this line: `MessageBox.Show(e.Result);`. There just is no valid response. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.uploadstringcompletedeventargs.result%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

You can determine if such an error occurred by checking the `Error` property of `UploadStringCompletedEventArgs` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.uploadstringcompletedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).